# How to read a local file json in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Help I need to read a json file in app with ionic and i'm started in this theme and i don't know how do this.

Ok So in this class is a provider in this case I put data from https://randomuser.me

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class SoilsServeProvider {

constructor(public http: Http) {

}
getUsers() {
return this.http.get('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=15')
.map(res => res.json())
.toPromise();
}

}
```

in another class I put this, in the controller

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SoilsServeProvider } from '../../providers/soils-serve/soils-
serve';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-cultivos',
templateUrl: 'cultivos.html',
})
export class CultivosPage {
users: any[] = [];
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
public userService: SoilsServeProvider) {
}

ionViewDidLoad(){
this.userService.getUsers()
.then(data => {
  this.users = data.results;
})
.catch(error =>{
  console.error(error);
})
}
}
```

finally en the view

```
<ion-header>
<ion-navbar color="primary">
<ion-title>
  Demo 10
</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img [src]="user.picture.medium">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{ user.name.first | uppercase }}</h2>
  <p>{{ user.email }}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and the result is this

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68AM4.png)

this example it's ok but I want read data from a local json, for example the path it's app/assets/data.json

Answer (score 1):

To read JSON file. I placed JSON file under src/assets.

```
Write This function 
try {
      this.services.getJSon().subscribe(result => {
        this.questionList = result.examList;
        console.log(this.questionList);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Profile" + e);
    }

This function within Services

getJSon() :any{
    return this.http.get('assets/data/test.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use the native file plugin to read the files in your device

> [Native File Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/)